# Errors resulting in YSOD when I deploy the app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, elmah

I have an app that runs fine locally. When I deploy this app to our staging environment, errors that are normally caught are resulting in the 'Yellow Screen of Death', even though the errors are surrounded by Try/Catch blocks and are being logged with ELMAH.

I have no idea why this is the case. Normally the app will deal with the error and keep working. Can somebody suggest what could be causing this?

I don't know what useful info to supply here, so please ask and I'll fill in as much as I can.

Comment: Can we see a the stack trace for the exception you're seeing? Is it a wide range of errors or something specific causing the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was a PEBKAC data-related error.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly sounds like a configuration issue. I'd suggest looking in the web.config in the `<system.web> <customErrors`... section.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give more info on what exception you're seeing?  Special cases like StackOverflowException are uncatchable.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception.aspx

StackOverflowException used to be catchable on old versions of .NET, but are not anymore.  Are your machines running different versions of the framework?

Comment: The error I'm getting is a NullReferenceException. All machines are running .Net Framework 3.5

Answer (score 0):

You could be missing some dependencies.  Make sure your staging environment has MVC installed.